# В БД не отправляется данные (Open server, PhpMyAdmin)

Tags: phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста данные не отправляется

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="kz">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>проблема</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="comment.php">
                <label for="Name">Аты - жөні</label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Аты - жөніңізді жазыңыз">

                <label for="Email">E - mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Электронды почтаңызды жазыңыз">

                <label for="Message">Пікір</label>
                <textarea id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Өз пікіріңізді қалдырыңыз" style="height:200px"></textarea>

                <input type="submit" value="Жіберу">
            </form>
</body>
</html>


    <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','Erbol');

        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $mess = $_POST['Message'];

    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `mess` (`id`, `Name`, `Email`, `Message`) VALUES (NULL, $name, $email, $mess)");
?>
```

в базу данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно будет `"INSERT INTO \`mess\` (\`id\`, \`Name\`, \`Email\`, \`Message\`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$email', '$mess')"`

Comment: поле id исключите из запроса. и не указывайте его как значение Null.
Так как у таблицы поле id настроено с авто_инкрементом